# TexShop autoclose environment and \stoping

Tags: texshop

I have noticed some strange behavior in TexShop (on a Mac) and I am hoping someone could explain to me what is going on. When I type "starting" (as text with no backslash) if further down the page I attempt to autoclose an environment (i.e. control+Apple Key+C) it inserts "\stoping".

Does anyone know why it does this? Does anyone know what the "\stoping" command should do?

Comment: Also `starti` and `startin` produce `\stopi` and `\stopin`; it seems that `start<anything non empty>` triggers insertion of `\stop<anything non empty>`. I guess it has to do with ConTeXt support, but it seems a bug anyway.

Comment: The autocompletion should, I think, be engine-specific if I remember correctly. (It is a while since I used TeXShop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “close environment shortcut” seems to work independently of the used engine. So it also closes ConTeXt environments and

```
\starttext
...
<hit Command-Control-C>
```

will type `\stoptext`. However it seems that a backslash is not really needed to recognize the start (for reasons unknown to me), so

```
starting
...
<hit Command-Control-C>
```

will insert `\stoping`.

This seems a bug in TeXShop.